# VB6 base64 Binary

Tags: web-services, soap, vb6, base64

I have a problem on this webservice:

http://credenciados.pronto.com.br/carga.asmx?op=IncluirMultimidia2

on **arrayArquivo** parameter, i use this function to generate data:

```
Private Function getBase64fromFile(Filename) As String

   Dim base64 As New cls64base

   Dim FileInputData() As Byte

   Open Filename For Binary As #1
   FileInputData = String(LOF(1), 0)
   Get #1, 1, FileInputData
   Close #1

   getBase64fromFile = base64.Base64Encode(FileInputData)

End Function
```

When i Call the service i receive this error:

**Type conversion failure for element arrayArquivo**

**Obs:**

Im using:

- Microsoft Soap ToolKit 3.0
- Visual Basic 6

Comment: Of course, to reduce dependencies, one could also consider to make an own encoding/decoding tool, as base64 conversions are not really a demanding task: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what this problem is, but I use the following pair of routines to get binary data from a file, then base64 encode it.  Code requires the MSXML library - I use version 3, which should be available to all Win2K+ versions.

For getting the binary data from a file:

```
Public Function GetFileData(ByVal Filename As String) As Byte()

    Dim f As Integer

    f = FreeFile

    Open Filename For Binary Access Read As #f
    ReDim GetFileData(0 To LOF(f) - 1)
    Get #f, , GetFileData
    Close #f

End Function
```

For converting the byte array into a base64 string:

```
Public Function GetBase64String(ByRef data() As Byte) As String

    Dim doc As DOMDocument
    Dim root As IXMLDOMElement

    Set doc = New DOMDocument
    Set root = doc.createElement("encode")
    root.dataType = "bin.base64"
    root.nodeTypedValue = data

    GetBase64String = root.Text

Exit Function
```